# Magento 2 Product import error :Value for 'status' attribute contains incorrect value, see acceptable values on settings specified for Admin in row

Tags: magento2, product, status, product-import

I am trying to import a csv of products having almost 6000 products. All the fields are validating correctly the only issue is with `product_online` i.e **status attribute**.

If keep the `product_online` attribute value as blank from all the products, CSV is validated correctly. But when trying to put `1` or `0` value for `enabled`, `disabled` statuses it throws following error

Can please some one guide me on what value needs to be used for enabled disabled statuses of products in magento 2?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should put 1 in product_online and should work fine.  Works fine in 2.3.2.  Try exporting a product to be sure you have the correct csv formated file